# Kendo inline editing with IEnumerable Model property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'd appreciate if someone could advise on following:

I have a model containing a collection of another model:

```
public class ContractModel
{
    public ContractModel()
    {
          this.ContractCurrencyClauses = new HashSet<ContractCurrencyClause>();
    }
    public System.Guid ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ContractCurrencyClause> ContractCurrencyClauses { get; set; }

   //other model properties
}

public partial class ContractCurrencyClause
{
    public System.Guid ID {get; set;} //PK
    public System.Guid CONTRACT_ID { get; set; } //FK on ContractModel(ID)
    public string CURRENCY { get; set; } 
    public Nullable<decimal> RATE { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that I am not sure how to temporarily store the collection of `ContractCurrencyClauses` when `ContractModel` is being created. 
I pass to my view the new instance of `ContractModel`:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ContractModel Contract = context.Contracts.Create();
        Contract.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        return PartialView(Contract);
    }
```

And in my view:

```
@model ContractModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", null, new AjaxOptions() { ... }))
{
@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.ID)

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.ContractCurrencyClauses)
               .Name("ContractCurrencyClauses")
               .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
               .Columns(columns => {
                        columns.Bound(u => u.ID).Hidden(true);
                        columns.Bound(u => u.CONTRACT_ID).Hidden(true);
                        columns.Bound(u => u.CURRENCY);
                        columns.Bound(u => u.RATE);
                        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); });
                        })

                        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
                        .DataSource(dataSource => 
                                dataSource.Ajax()
                                .Model(model =>
                                {
                                    model.Id(u => u.ID);                                        
                                    model.Field(u => u.CONTRACT_ID).DefaultValue(Model.ID);
                                    model.Field(u => u.ID).DefaultValue(Guid.NewGuid());
                                })
                         .Create(create => create.Action("CreateCurClause", "Contracts"))
                         .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateCurClause", "Contracts"))
                         .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DestroyCurClause", "Contracts")))
                )
 }
```

My first issue when I submit new entry of grid, I receive `null` for `ContractCurrencyClause` model:

```
 public ActionResult CreateCurClause([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, ContractCurrencyClause clause)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        return Json(new[] { clause }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

I guess this is because new instance of the model was not created, when i press `Add` button in the grid toolbar, because I see the JS error: Cannot read property `ID` of `null`.

Second, I don't know how to bind and store `Model.ContractCurrencyClauses` temporarily, so that the whole collection was passed when user submits the main form.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 2:**

### **ContractsController**

```
 public class ContractsController : Controller
    {
        //
        // Static variables for Demo only
        static ContractModel model;
        static ICollection<ContractCurrencyClause> tmpContractCurrencyClauses { get; set; }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (model == null)
            {
             model = new ContractModel();
             tmpContractCurrencyClauses = new HashSet<ContractCurrencyClause>();
             model.ContractCurrencyClauses = tmpContractCurrencyClauses;
            }
            model.ContractCurrencyClauses = tmpContractCurrencyClauses;
            return View(model);
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Create(ContractCurrencyClause contract)
        {
            contract.CONTRACT_ID = new Guid();
            tmpContractCurrencyClauses.Add(contract);
            RouteValueDictionary routeValues = this.GridRouteValues();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", routeValues);
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Update(ContractCurrencyClause contract)
        {
            tmpContractCurrencyClauses.Add(contract);
            RouteValueDictionary routeValues = this.GridRouteValues();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", routeValues);
        }
    }
```

### Index.cshtml

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.ID)
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.ContractCurrencyClauses)
               .Name("ContractCurrencyClauses")
               .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
               .Columns(columns => {
                        columns.Bound(u => u.CONTRACT_ID).Hidden(true);
                        columns.Bound(u => u.CURRENCY);
                        columns.Bound(u => u.RATE);
                        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); });
                        })

                        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
                        .DataSource(dataSource => 
                                dataSource.Ajax()
                                .Model(model =>
                                {
                                    model.Id(u => u.CONTRACT_ID);
                                    //model.Id(u => u.CURRENCY);  Kendo datasource does not support composite data keys.  
                                     model.Field(u => u.CONTRACT_ID).DefaultValue(Model.ID);
                                })
                         .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "Contracts"))
                         .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Contracts"))
                         .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DestroyCurClause", "Contracts")))
                )
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create(ContractCurrencyClause contract)
    {
     ...
    }
```

Have you tried placing the kendo grid outside of form ?

As per the Kendo documentation

> The Kendo UI MVC Grid uses form elements internally when server
>   editing is enabled. This means the widget cannot be placed in another
>   form element on the page, because nesting forms is not
>   standard-compliant.

also verify the the create, update method signature with the [kendo doc](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/server-editing).

should you need to send all data at once you can serialize the grid like this

```
var form data = JSON.stringify(dataSource.data());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I placed kendo grid outside the form, but I still receive null in controller, and JS error: Cannot read property 'ID' of null

Comment: can u change the create method as mentioned on Edit 1

Comment: Still null, I added .Batch(true) and .ServerOperation(false), now my model is not null in the controller, but all fields are null or zeros (for Guid)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a better solution, I use `InCell` editing:

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.ContractCurrencyClauses)
                          .Name("ContractCurrencyClauses")
                          .ToolBar(toolbar => { toolbar.Create(); })
                          .Columns(columns => {
                              columns.Bound(p => p.CONTRACT_ID).Hidden().ClientTemplate("#= CONTRACT_ID #" +
                                "<input type='hidden' name='ContractCurrencyClauses[#= index(data)#].CONTRACT_ID' value='#= CONTRACT_ID #' />"
                              );                                  
                              columns.Bound(p => p.CURRENCY).ClientTemplate("#= CURRENCY #" +
                               "<input type='hidden' name='ContractCurrencyClauses[#= index(data)#].CURRENCY' value='#= CURRENCY #' />"
                              ).EditorTemplateName("CurrencyDDL");

                              columns.Bound(p => p.RATE).ClientTemplate("#= RATE #" +
                               "<input type='hidden' name='ContractCurrencyClauses[#= index(data)#].RATE' value='#= RATE #' />"
                              );

                              columns.Command(command => { command.Destroy(); });
                          })
                        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).CreateAt(GridInsertRowPosition.Bottom))
                        .DataSource(dataSource => 
                            dataSource.Ajax()
                            .Model(model =>
                            {
                                model.Id(u => u.CONTRACT_ID);
                                model.Field(u => u.CONTRACT_ID).DefaultValue(Model.ID);                                   
                            })
                            .ServerOperation(false)
                            )
            )

<script>
    function index(dataItem) {
        var data = $("#ContractCurrencyClauses").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
        return data.indexOf(dataItem);
    }
</script>
```

The grid is inside my main form, and when i sumbit it, i receive the whole list of `ContractCurrencyClauses` in my controller.

Simillar solution here: [Project](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/submit-form-containing-grid-along-with-other-input-elements)